# Error resolving dependencies in npm: ERESOLVE code with conflicting React versions

Tags: reactjs, npm, vercel

n error while trying to host my website on Vercel:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@12.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (react-dom, react-icons, react-router, react-router-dom, react-scripts)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!   react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!     react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-26T16_11_46_052Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-26T16_11_46_052Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

How to resolve this dependency conflict?

Comment: Did you read it? It gives a lot of detail on what the conflict is.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a dependency conflict related to conflicting versions of React in your project. The error message indicates that the package `react-typed` has a peer dependency on an older version of `React (16.3.0)`, while your root project and other packages depend on a newer version of `React (17.0.2)`.

*To resolve this issue, you can consider the following options:*

1. **Update react-typed**: Check if there is a newer version of the `react-typed` package available that is compatible with `React 17`. Try updating the `react-typed` package to the latest version that supports `React 17`. You can do this by modifying the dependency version in your project's `package.json` file and then running `npm install`.
2. **Downgrade React**: If the `react-typed` package is crucial for your project and there is no updated version available, you may need to downgrade the React version used by your project to `16.3.0` to satisfy the peer dependency requirement. Modify the React version in your `package.json` file to `16.3.0` and run `npm install`

After implementing the necessary changes, run `npm install` again to resolve the dependencies. If the issue persists, check the generated error report and debug log mentioned in the error message to get a more detailed understanding of the conflicts.

Good luck!